# Is there a way to mark a parent's virtual function final from a child class without reimplementing it

Tags: c++, c++11

If I have the code:

```
struct Parent
{
    virtual void fn();
};

struct Child : public Parent
{
    virtual void fn() override final
    {
        Parent::fn();
    }
};
```

is there a way to have `Parent::fn` be `final` only when accessed through `Child` without re-implementing `fn`, so that some other `class` can override `fn` when deriving from `Parent` but not when deriving from `Child`?

like:

```
struct Child : public Parent
{
    virtual void fn() override final = Parent::fn;
};
```

or some other syntax?

Comment: @songyuanyao I edited the question to hopefully be clearer.

Comment: `= Parent::fn;` vs `{ Parent::fn();}`.

Comment: `struct Child : public Parent` - `public` is redundant here. When you use `struct` you inherit `public`ly by default, with `class`es it's `private` by default.

Comment: @Patryk I like to put the redundant `public` in there to make it clearer -- I'd guess that most C++ programmers don't remember the specific rules for the default inheritance access specifier as I had thought that both `struct` and `class` inherited `private`-ly by default before I checked the standard, though I'd consider myself an expert c++ programmer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you can't do it without reimplementing it. So just reimplement it:

```
struct Child : public Parent
{
    virtual void fn() override final { Parent::fn(); }
};
```

N.B. saying `virtual ... override final` is entirely redundant, `final` is an error on a non-virtual function, so you should just say:

```
    void fn() final { Parent::fn(); }
```

See http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rh-override

Comment: well, I guess I have a proposal for c++20 then.

Comment: related, do you think that reimplementing it in order to mark it `final` or leaving the base class's implementation alone will help a compiler to optimize better, potentially allowing the compiler to devirtualize and inline?

Comment: I doubt there will be interest in such a proposal, you can already do it easily enough. There are far more important things to spend time standardising.

Comment: I think the reimplementation marked `final` has more potential to be devirtualized, because it's final. If you don't do that then when the dynamic type of the object is not known the compiler doesn't know if there is another override in something deriving from `Child`.

Comment: Redundancy, where you repeat something that is already implied or expressed elsewhere, can drive home a point, or make it more clear and understood by the reader.  More seriously, I disagree with the core guidelines on destructors; they should be marked override if they override, simply to catch the "oops, parent doesn't have virtual" errors.

Comment: @Yakk, this is not the place for a discussion about the destructor guidance :) I'm ambivalent and I have no horse in that race.

Comment: “so you should just say: `void fn() final { Parent::fn(); }`”

I disagree with this. I would say marking it virtual is better, since it states the intent more clearly.

Comment: @MartinKočička the intention is for it to be a final overrider, and that's what `final` means. `final` implies `virtual`.